# Cool down function for skill button in mobile game

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I want to include a cool down function to my skill button in my mobile game that I am currently developing. So I wanted to allow the player to only be able to use the skill button once every few seconds.

Left button is my default skill button and right one is a duplicate. The default skill button will be placed over the duplicate so when I run the game, upon clicking on the default skill button, the duplicate will overlap the default skill button.

[image: Skill Button Comparison]

However, in my case the duplicate is not able to overlap the default skill button so it does not show the cool down timer.

I am wondering if I need to include a set of codes to allow the default skill button to turn inactive upon clicking or do I just have to sort the layers?

My current codes are as such:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Abilities : MonoBehaviour
{
public Image abilityImage1;
public float cooldown = 5;
bool isCooldown = false;
public Button ability1;

void Start()
{
    abilityImage1.fillAmount = 0;
    ability1.onClick.AddListener(AbilityUsed);
}

private void AbilityUsed()
{
    if (isCooldown)
        return;
    isCooldown = true;
    abilityImage1.fillAmount = 1;
    StartCoroutine(LerpCooldownValue());
}

private IEnumerator LerpCooldownValue()
{
    float currentTime = 0;
    while (currentTime < cooldown)
    {
        abilityImage1.fillAmount = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, currentTime / 
 cooldown);
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    abilityImage1.fillAmount = 0;
    isCooldown = false;
}
}
```

The first picture is my original skill button and on the bottom is a duplicate which I made to adjust the color to create an overlay effect for the cool down.

[image: Skill Button] [image: Skill button 1]
[image: Code Inspector]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lerp instead of changing fill amount in Update() method

```
void Start()
{
    abilityImage1.fillAmount = 0;
    ability1.onClick.AddListener(AbilityUsed);
}

private void AbilityUsed()
{
    if (isCooldown)
        return;
    isCooldown = true;
    abilityImage1.fillAmount = 1;
    StartCoroutine(LerpCooldownValue());
}

private IEnumerator LerpCooldownValue()
{
    float currentTime = 0;
    while (currentTime < cooldown)
    {
        abilityImage1.fillAmount = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, currentTime / cooldown);
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    abilityImage1.fillAmount = 0;
    isCooldown = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi this is working fine for me but one issue that I faced is that my duplicate is hiding behind the original skill button. I'm not sure how to make the original skill button inactive and allow the duplicate to appear. Could you help me on this? I've made edits to the original question that I posted

Comment: just move your cooldown image lower in hierarchy than your skill image

Comment: haha yeah i figured that out. quite dumb of me. thanks anyway!